# Find Unique Custom Field value linked to Custom Post Type

Tags: repeater, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to list name of all authors (which is a repeater field) linked to a custom post type - Publications however I'm not able to get the authors list. Each publication when added has a Repeater field 'linked_author' with sub-field 'paper_linked_author' through which multiple Authors are linked.

The sub-field 'paper_linked_author' is a post_object and is actually a custom post_type - people.

The final unique list of authors will be displayed in an Accordion and when clicked will show all the publications they are linked to. I have yet to work on this code though...

The list is nor generated! If I echo something, the loop is working fine until foreach ( $the_posts as $the_post ) {, but after that there is no echo. Where is it that is wrong?

Here is the code.

```
 $the_posts = get_posts( array(
'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'post_type'      => 'publications',
'order'             => 'DESC'

));

foreach ( $the_posts as $the_post ) {

if(have_rows('linked_author')) : // linked_author is the Repeater field

  while ( have_rows('linked_author') ) : the_row();
    $post_object = get_sub_field('paper_linked_author'); 
    echo '<ul>';
        if( $post_object ):

              $post = $post_object;
              setup_postdata( $post );

              echo '<li>';
              echo '<a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>';
              echo '</li>';
        endif;
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endwhile;
  endif;

 }
```

Comment: $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type'     => 'publications'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $the_query->posts, 'ID' );

$artist_list = array();

foreach($post_ids as $post_id){
    
 $artist_repeater = get_field('linked_author', $post_id);
 
    if (is_array($artist_repeater)) {
  
        foreach($artist_repeater as $paper_linked_author){
  
   echo $nicename = $paper_linked_author->ID;
   
   
            array_push($artist_list, $paper_linked_author);
        }
    }
}
 ?>

Comment: I tried to rewrite the code as in above comment but the echo $nicename = $paper_linked_author->ID;  does not show anything.